# Attachments.Add wildcard with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a ZIP file generated with dynamic information (Report_ PC Name-Date_User). However when I go to attach the file I'm unable to use a wildcard. There is only one ZIP file in this directory so using a wildcard will not attach any other ZIP files.

```
#Directory storage
    $DIR = "$ENV:TEMP"

    #Max number of recent screen captures
    $MAX = "100"

    #Captures Screen Shots from the recording
    $SC = "1"

    #Turn GUI mode on or off
    $GUI = "0"

    #Caputres the current computer name
    $PCName = "$ENV:COMPUTERNAME"

    #Use either the local name or domain name
    #$User = "$ENV:UserDomainName"
    $User = "$ENV:UserName"

    #Timestamp
    $Date = Get-Date -UFormat %Y-%b-%d_%H%M

    #Computer Information
    $MAC = ipconfig /all | Select-String Physical
    $IP = ipconfig /all | Select-String IPv4
    $DNS = ipconfig /all | Select-String "DNS Servers"

    #Needed to add space after user input information
    $EMPT = "`n"

    #Quick capture of the computer information
    $Info = @"
    $EMPT
*** COMPUTER INFORMATION ***

    $PCName
    $IP
    $MAC
    $DNS
"@

    # Used to attach to the outlook program
    $File = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Filter "*.zip" | Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Fullname


    $Start_Click = {
        psr.exe /start /output $DIR\$Date-$PCName-$User.zip /maxsc $MAX /sc $SC /gui $GUI
    }

    $Stop_Click={
        psr.exe /stop
    }

    $Email_Click = {    
        $Outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
        $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
        $Mail.To = "deaconf19@gmail.com"
        $Mail.Subject = "Capture Report from " + $PCName + " " + $User + " " + $Date
        $Mail.Body = $Problem.text + $Info
        $Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
        $Mail.Send()
    }
```

I no longer get an error but the file will not attach the first time around. The second time it will attach but it does the previous .zip not the most recent. I added my entire code

Comment: You need to check if the file exists and is readable. Perhaps it takes time to finalize the zip file? Use `Test-Path` to see if the zip exists before you attempt to attach it. Also if this is still an issue please consider making another question as we have solved your current one. Who's to say you wont have another issue after you address this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add) it shows what the source needs to be which is.

> The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the
>   full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that
>   constitutes the attachment.

Which mean that it does not accept wildcards. To get around this you should instead use `Get-ChildItem` to return the name of your zip.

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dir -Filter "*.zip" | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Fullname
```

That should return the full path to the first zip. Since Get-ChildItem returns and object we use `-ExpandProperty` on the `Fullname` so that you just return the full path, as a string, to the file. `-First 1` is not truly required if you really only have the one file. On the off-chance you do including `-First 1` will make sure only one file is attached.

**Update from comments**

I see that you are having issues with attaching a file still. My code would still stand however you might be having an issue with your .zip file or `$dir`. After where `$file` is declared I would suggest something like this:

```
If (! Test-Path $file){Write-Host "$file is not a valid zip file"}
```

If you would prefer, since I don't know if you see your console when you are running your code, you could use a [popup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/04/powertip-use-powershell-to-display-pop-up-window.aspx)

Comment: Thanks my problem has been solved I also needed to change a few outlook settings but works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry for this but, it is and isn't working. When I run the scrip the first time the .zip file is not attached when I run it the second time it attaches the .zip file that was just created? I'm not sure why.

Comment: What are the contents of `$file` when it fails? Also I don't know the contents of `$dir` so there might be an issue there.

Comment: Are you able to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61634/attachments-add-wildcard-with-powershell

Comment: I fixed the problem for good I placed your fix within the function of the submit email and it worked fine. Thanks for the help again